# How to find out if a certain struct exists in a mapping

Tags: solidity, contract-development

i am trying to verify in a contract method, that a struct exists in a mapping while having it's address. here is what i tried.
Note : i have the UserAddress.

```
function DeleteAUser(address UserAddress) onlyOwner{
    require(users[UserAddress] > 0);
    delete users[UserAddress] ;
}
```

**AND**

```
function DeleteAUser(address UserAddress) onlyOwner{
    require(users[UserAddress] != bytes4(0x0));
    delete users[UserAddress] ;
}
```

**EDIT** : As you can see i only have the Address as input to the function.

but still has an error of operator compatibility :

```
TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types struct Ownership.User storage ref and bytes4
```

Is there anyway to solve this ?

Comment: Can you provide more code? What is your struct?  Can't you just check if one of the field exits? Like require(users[address].exists == true)

Comment: well your solution is quite a workaround actually, and using workarounds it not always the best idea and it needs me to add an other property `exist` to my struct.

Comment: But the thing is that if the struct you are trying to delete does not exists, it wont delete anything. It will not cause any problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to test for the existence of something in a `mapping`. In the EVM, anything that hasn't already been written to in storage has the value 0.

So you'll always get back a struct when you read from the mapping; all the values will just be zero.

If you can just test for a zero (e.g. `users[UserAddress].balance == 0` is sufficient), go ahead and do that. If you need something more definitive, use an explicit existence `bool` like `!users[UserAddress.balance].exists`.

Comment: How about if there is multiple mappings, such as `users[userAddress][job][index]` ? @smarx

Comment: That doesn't change the answer.

Comment: If `storage reference` does not exist this seems like does not work.

Comment: You may need to ask a new question so you can share your code and explain further. I don't know what you mean by "does not exist."

Comment: `[index]` was coming the pushed struct with same `job` string. So checking  `users[userAddress][job].length == 0` solved my problem.

Comment: In that case, you had an array somewhere, not a mapping.